# Can cookie values be set after html has loaded on a page?

Tags: php, html, cookies

I read that cookie values can be set after HTML content has been sent from a PHP script to the web server.

However, when working with this, I have not been able to set the cookies as I had hoped. Can someone straighten out my discrepancy?

Comment: @Mr.Alien I'm really more curious about the implications wthin php, if you could address that problem. Is it not possible to set a cookie after displaying content?

Comment: Once a page has loaded, you can't set a cookie in PHP without making another page request. Javascript can though.

Comment: @ZAX if your source code outputs php, you set a cookie in between output html again on footer, cookie gets set, 1ce the page is rendered, you cannot set using php, use JS instead, be sure you dont have any useful functionality depending on cookies, if user browser JS is turned off, you may be in trouble

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP can only set cookies while sending the headers of the page (that is, before sending the content - the HTML).
This is how the [HTTP protocol works regarding cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie), the server can send a request to the browser to store cookies.

If you wish to add cookies after the page loaded, you can do it via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a javascript cookie (somewhat simple with the [jQuery plugin](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/))—or send a value via AJAX to a php script, and have it set the cookie. Or best option possibly, you could use sessions instead of cookies on the PHP level. Depends on your application.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you haven't [RTM](http://php.net/setcookie) because if you had you would of seen this:

> setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the
>   HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any
>   output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This
>   requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output,
>   including  and  tags as well as any whitespace.

But more importantly in your case, this:

> Note:
>
> You can use output buffering to send output prior to the call of this
>   function, with the overhead of all of your output to the browser being
>   buffered in the server until you send it. You can do this by calling
>   ob_start() and ob_end_flush() in your script